Did Elon Musk's team assemble a cluster of GPUs in 19 days which would usually have taken 4 years?
I saw this headline recently

Elon Musk set up 100,000 Nvidia H200 GPUs in 19 days - Jensen says process normally takes 4 years

It can also be found in various other media stories.
Is there truth to this estimated timeline? Does it really take 4 years, and did Elon's team really do it in 19 days? Is there some technological breakthrough here?

Interesting, yes - but your second link states: "The "nineteen days" remark is a little misleading, though; that's the time from hardware setup to its first functional use for AI training. The full Colossus project was set up in 122 days from start to finish,". It seems possible that the first bit, the LLM  could even have been set up on a single PC with more hardware (bandwidth, capacity) added later.

100K GPUs in 19 days is 20K per day. There are 86400 seconds in a day so this implies they took slightly more than four seconds per GPU. Simple math suggests they used a massive amount of automation and the clickbait media just made up the most dramatic headline possible.

100 k gpus is 5k per days. And you will have many more than one GPU on a card.

122 days to build the 100K GPU xAI Colossus Cluster and, according to Nvidia, "it took 19 days from the time the first rack rolled onto the floor until training began". Supposing 200 GPUs per server cabinets, 500 units need to be installed and interconnected, i.e. 25 per day.

This seems to just be picking different spots for start time on a project roadmap? Standing up 1200 cabinets in an existing, wired data center in 19 days might be a bit fast, but 4 years is absurdly long. 4 years is a reasonable estimate for starting from an empty field or a building shell though. Is there anything specific in any of these claims about what they're comparing?

One should add an unknown time to the said 122 days since those 122 days are counted "From the moment that we decided to go" looks like there were things being done that led to the decision. It is also not clear what was already ready at the site. For "generic" data centers this or this shows that it is possible to build a data center from scratch (i.e. from not even having electricity or a building) in less than 1.5 years. Leaving this as a comment since there are many unknowns here.

@CJR also, it takes 4 years for who? A random company that might have to contend with GPU being available is a lot different than Musk just being able to throw money at the problem, also for the better or worse being associated with his name is a guaranteed way to be on every news network so Nvidia probably has at least a slight incentive in accommodating his requests. I am not saying it's not a monumental task but it seems like a very cherrypicked example

Not an answer, but maybe a good direction for research: this was the newest cluster that was brought online. Everybody else started earlier than that, with older hardware designs. Companies have learned a lot over the past years, even just months. Nvidia and its partners are now delivering fully pre-built, pre-wired, pre-configured racks complete with servers, GPUs, network switches, power distribution, and water cooling. All you need is roll those racks off the truck into your datacenter, plug in power, hot and cold water, and a couple of fibers, and you're off to the races.

Another point: the H200 was released in August 2024, less than 5 months ago, so I find it hard to see how someone could have taken 4 years to install them.
